# Including jQuery as different var

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I include a jQuery as a different named var? I want to reference to a specific jQuery with different vars.

I am aware of wrapping a js file like this.. but if i update the jQuery it needs to be always wrapped like this.

```
(function ($) {
    var blabla = something;
})(someJquery);
```

Is there a way to do int a way that allows me to easily update the jQuery and not always wrap it like this?

e.g.

```
<script>someJquery</script>
<script>
#use this jquery as a var called jQuery2
</script>
```

Comment: use jQuery.noConflict()

Answer (score 2):

Stright from the [jQuery.noConflict() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/):

Load two versions of jQuery (not recommended). Then, restore jQuery's globally scoped variables to the first loaded jQuery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.noConflict demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
// (the newer version)

jQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict( true );

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jQuery2): " + jQuery2.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
Before $.noConflict(true)

2nd loaded jQuery version ($): 1.6.2
After $.noConflict(true)

1st loaded jQuery version ($): 1.10.2
2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): 1.6.2
```